# Angular4 CLI i18n mutiple files for the same language

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if i18n provided by angular4, not ngx-translate, can support mutiple files for the same language.

For exampla, I want to separate messages.en.xlf to messages1.en.xlf, messages2.en.xlf and so on, but they all for English. Can i18n pick all thrse files together and then use like one file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and testing, the `I18NHtmlParser` in Angular only takes one file for translation. I had discovered this after attempting this myself. Would love if this idea changes as Angular evolves in the future for large applications.